# Possible to add more than one Page Content area on a publishing page layout?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-site, publishing-page

I'm building a new page layout in SPD10, and I've run into a question.  Is it possible to have more than one page content area on a publishing page?  I've tried adding more than one and it doesn't seem to recognize the additional ones.

Let me explain why I'm asking (because there may be a better/different way to achieve what I'm trying to do).  I would like to build a page layout that will provide specific sections for a publishing page (such as video on upper left, with content on upper right, and then smaller content sections on the lower left, middle, and right - see attached mockup - so that there's a standard look across all pages of this type).  [image: Mockup of desired layout]

I've currently set it up as a publishing page that includes webparts (see attached page layout). [image: Page Layout Image]
My thought process here was that we would just use a media webpart in the upper left column web part zone, then a content webpart in the upper right column zone.  I would then add an image webpart to the lower left and right column (which are just two columns, but may end up being three as the mockup shows - playing with how the content fits right now) so that I could create branded images for those section headers (since the formatting of the heading within the Summary Links zones is very limited).

However, I'm finding that the media webpart doesn't work right, and it's just easier to embed a viewer using HTML, so I'm having to use a content webpart with HTML coding.  But once I put HTML coding into the Content webpart, it ends up acting strangely and will not open the edit HTML option again, so I end up having to delete the webpart and start new each time I need to change the HTML, which is ESPECIALLY not productive or efficient.  Also, in order to do the kind of branding within the other sections, I'm also using HTML coding, so it would seem easier to just use the Page Content sections since it's much easier than having to add a webpart each time.

**Which brings me back to my original question: is there a way to have more than one Page Content section on a publishing page layout?**  While I can add multiple ones without error in SPD, when I publish the layout and use it on a page, only one Page Content section actually shows up to edit.  Any ideas or suggestions?  Any resources that walk through how to do this?  Any links or specific how-to steps would be really helpful.  I know enough to be dangerous, but I'm self-teaching a lot of this design work since SP design is its own beast.  :)  Thanks in advance for your thoughts and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

> Can’t see more multiple content areas in edit mode? Two Rich HTML
>   Fields showing the same content? To create a custom layout in
>   SharePoint Designer with multiple page content areas (RichHTMLField
>   fields), you should first create a custom page content type and add
>   one custom field for each of the content areas you have in your custom
>   layout. For example, PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id=”…”
>   FieldName=”CustomFieldNameGoesHere” requires that you add a
>   “CustomFieldNameGoesHere” column to the content type that your layout
>   will be attached to.  FieldName and the column name should match, and
>   each set must be unique.

http://5280solutions.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/custom-layout-with-multiple-content-fields-a-k-a-page-content-areas/